# "Click to show spoiler" should be "Tap to show spoiler"

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, wording, spoilers

I've noticed the other day when using the mobile app, the spoiler said "Click to show spoiler"

[image]

<sup>*Sorry that it's not a freehand circle</sup>

Right now, this doesn't make the *most* sense as you really "tap" on the spoiler to reveal it. What I'm proposing is to change this to "Tap to show spoiler". This would make most sense as I can't imagine any scenario where you would be using a mouse with your phone.

Comment: Irrelevant, but how in the world did you get -1 notifications?

Comment: @bleh I cheated and just modified the html :p